# $_POST Empty with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-post

I was searching now quite a bit on the internet but can not find any solution.
I have an .htaccess file, which rewrites my query string into the GET variable.
This works absolutely fine.

when it comes to the POST variable, it is the first time I get into this trouble.
I have used this .htaccess file already a lot of times on different servers, but now one of my client's server doesn't want to work.
When ever I post a form the whole POST variable is empty... I will post my .htaccess file, any help is appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^pages.*$ /error/404 [L]
RewriteRule ^classes.*$ /error/404 [L]
RewriteRule ^templates.*$ /error/404 [L]
RewriteRule ^common.*$ /error/404 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /?p=$1&s=index&a=index&n=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /?p=$1&s=$2&a=index&n=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /?p=$1&s=$2&a=$3&n=index&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /?p=$1&s=$2&a=$3&n=$4&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /?p=$1&s=$2&a=$3&n=$4&o=$5&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

the form looks like this

```
        <div class="login">
            <form action="/administrator" method="post">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="passwort" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Anmelden" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and the login php file like this

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] === TRUE ) {
    header('Location: /administrator');
    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];

    $hostname = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $path     = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    if ($username == 'xxx' && $passwort == 'xxx') {
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header('Location: /administrator');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you put `var_dump($_POST)` output here?

Comment: The $_POST is an empty array... Absolutely nothing in there...

Comment: can you put rewrite log here?

Comment: sorry do not have access to the apache log file.
The apache is an Apache 2 and therefore I can not set the RewriteLog file in the .htaccess...

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule are active for GET, not for POST.

1. check if your `/administrator` script (why haven't you called it directly as administrator.php?) is called or create a rule for its access. Check in the access log to be sure you're calling the script when you post to it.
2. Add something like :

   - `RewriteRule ^administrator      administrator.php    [L]`
   - or `RewriteRule ^administrator      pathtoyourscript/administrator.php    [L]`
3. check without session to be sure it's not interacting badly with it.

You can use var_dump($_POST) to display all data. If there is no display, you've not called the right script or your path is wrong.